# MySQL import csv file separated by tabulation

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I need to import a `CSV` file into a table named "coplaints". The file is separated by tabulation. I already tried this:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/rocket/Documents/filipe ferminiano/processos/segmentacao/912013/coplaint.csv' 
into table crm_base.coplaints fields terminated by ' ' enclosed by '"';
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the result? If you are getting an error message, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\t` as your field terminator for a tab separated file.

```
load data local infile 
'C:/Users/rocket/Documents/filipe ferminiano/processos/segmentacao/912013/coplaint.csv'
into table crm_base.coplaints fields terminated by '\t' enclosed by '"';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html